# Register/change method from other class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, overriding

I wonder what is the proper way to assign/override a method from that of another class. For example, here below classes A and B are not and should not be subclassed, but method "A.foo" is a prototype and should be assinged/set in the initialization of B. That is, "A.foo = B.bar_b" (or C or D etc). (The overall idea is to register a send method of servers (B) with a client (A).)

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void foo(arg argA) {
    // empty
  };
};

class B {
public:
  B(A a) {
    a.foo = &B::bar_b;
  }
  void bar_b(arg argA) {
    // do stuff B
  };
};

A a;
B b(a);
a.foo(arg) // calls bar_b
```

Comment: Why should A not be subclassed if it has a virtual method?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please explain what you want to achieve (not only how you want to get there). And note that you cannot call `B::bar_b` without a `B` instance.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. There are two ways to answer your question. The first is to use proper overriding:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void foo() {
    // empty
  };
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void foo() override {
    // do stuff B
  };
};

B b;
A& b_ref = b;
b_ref.foo();   // calls B::foo
```

The other way is trying to interpret what you actually want to do. Perhaps you want to swap some implementation at runtime to select what `A::foo` is actually doing.

You need a `B` to call a method of the class `B`. Also `B(A a)` passes the `A` by value and the assignment in the constructor wont have any effect on the `A` you pass. Though, most importantly you cannot dynamically assign member functions. However, you can assign to member variables:

```
#include <functional>

struct A {
public:
  void foo() {
      do_foo();
  };
  std::function<void()> do_foo;
};

class B {
public:
  B() = default;
  B(A& a) {
    a.do_foo = [](){B b; b.bar_b(); };
  }
  void bar_b() {};
};
```